# Form cannot get the value in php using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms, bootstrapping

My old HTML program working fine.

```
<body>
<h1 align="center" class="color"> Welcome advanced Search </h1>
<center>
<div>
<label>Field:</label> 
<select name="country" class="country">
<option selected="selected">--Select Field--</option>
<?php
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM country");
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['country_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['country_name']; ?></option>
        <?php
    } 
?>
</select>
<label>Department :</label> 
<select name="state" class="state">
<option selected="selected">--Select Department--</option>
</select>
```

Instead off am using Bootstrap to implement/Integrate the code. Like below.

```
<form class="form-inline form_search_form testingForm" autocomplete="off"  style="display:block" >

 <div class="row">                  

                  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <select title="Field" data-placement="left" name="country" class="form-control" class="country">
                        <option selected="selected"> -- Field -- </option>
  <? php
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM country");
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['country_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['country_name']; ?></option>
        <?php
    } 
 ?>                   

                     </select>

                     </div>
```

What the issue ?. In this case am using  or else ?.

I am totally confuse please help us. 
Actually i need to get the data from *mysql to my website*. ?

Comment: I think space between `<?` and `php` create problem!!

Comment: `<?php` instead of `<? php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right code:

```
<form class="form-inline form_search_form testingForm" autocomplete="off"  style="display:block" >

 <div class="row">                  

                  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <select title="Field" data-placement="left" name="country" class="form-control" class="country">
                        <option selected="selected"> -- Field -- </option>
  <?php
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM country");
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['country_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['country_name']; ?></option>
        <?php
    } 
 ?>                   

                     </select>

                     </div> 
</form>
```

End the Element with `</form>` and use `<?php` not `< ?php`

Comment: IN above bootstrap there has any issues ?. please help us

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="form-inline form_search_form testingForm" autocomplete="off"  style="display:block" >

 <div class="row">                  

                  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <select title="Field" data-placement="left" name="country" class="form-control" class="country">
                        <option selected="selected"> -- Field -- </option>
  <?php
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM country");
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['country_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['country_name']; ?></option>
        <?php
    } 
 ?>                   

                     </select>

                     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

Select Field 
  prepare("SELECT * FROM country");

    $stmt->execute();

    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
  ?>
     ">

Comment: With out assign to any variable, how its will work. Pls give sugg.